# Regarding `Variable (var-name) might not have been initialized`

Tags: java, error-handling

```
import java.io.*;

interface MyIOAction 
{
    void ioAction(Reader rdr) throws IOException;
}

class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Reader rdr1;

        int read = rdr1.read();    //Statement 1

        MyIOAction myIO = (rdr2) -> 
        {
            int ch = rdr2.read();    //Statement 2
        };
    }
}
```

In the above code, `Statement 1` produces the following error

> Variable `rdr1` might not have been initialized

Whereas `Statement 2` compiles successfully.

So, why the same error as in `Statement 1` is not produced in the `Statement 2`?

Comment: Why should there be a compile time error for statement 2? Are you asking what a lambda expression is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statement 2, `rdr2` is in essence a formal argument to a method. It is initialized when the method is invoked. See the [Lambda Quick Start](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) or [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) tutorials for more information about what's going on with statement 2.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables(variables declared inside a method body) `rdr1` should be initialized before use . However this rule
 does not applies to class variables(instance variables).They get their default type value.

As far as `rdr2` is concerned , it is Initialised when the method is called. More info about *Lambda Exp* [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {
            Reader rdr1; // local variable should be initialized before use

            int read = rdr1.read();    //Statement 1

            MyIOAction myIO = (rdr2) -> // initialized when method is called.Lambda Exp.
            {
                int ch = rdr2.read();    //Statement 2
            };
        }
```